# How are reactive forms scalable and reusable?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

A [guide](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#choosing-an-approach) to the key differences between template driven (what you have now) and reactive forms.

> In general:
>
> - Reactive forms are more robust: they're more **scalable, reusable**, and    testable. If forms are a key part of your application, or
>   you're    already using reactive patterns for building your
>   application, use    reactive forms.
> - Template-driven forms are useful for adding a simple form to an app,    such as an email list signup form. They're easy to add to an
>   app, but    they don't scale as well as reactive forms. If you have
>   very basic    form requirements and logic that can be managed solely
>   in the    template, use template-driven forms.

What do **scalable and reusable** exactly mean in that case? What happens under the hood?

Comment: It's nonsense in my opinion because both can be scaled it's just a matter of preference.  I like the Reactive forms because it adds awesome validation helpers!

Comment: @John Peters. Thank you for your response. I surfed through a lot blogs and other sites. Everybody "copy paste" that argument without an explanation. Maybe because scalibility is an headword which sounds clever and sells good nowadays.